# Surds (or square roots) and Irrationality

Tags: number-theory, education

**Sorry if this has been asked before, but can't find what I'm looking for on here.**

I'm currently preparing an early lesson for my new A-Level class about surds. I'd like to be quite formal and thorough with them and I'm struggling with a good way of communicating surds.

So for my own curiosity and for a good definition for my pupils I've got a couple of questions I'm hoping someone could answer.

So

Question 1: Are all square roots of prime numbers irrational, or square roots of non-perfect powers for that matter i.e. all $ n \in \mathbb{N}  , \text{where}  \ n \ne a^b$ for $ a, b \in \mathbb{N} $ ?

Question 2: If we define a surd as: $ \sqrt{p \cdot q .....} $

where $p,q...$ unique primes. Then is there anyway to guarantee that this will be irrational or is it a brute force method for each individual number taking the form of the $ \sqrt{2} $ proof.

Final question: What is a good definition of a surd? For me it's the square root of a number that has a prime decomposition in which no prime is raised to any power greater than 1.

Comment: A hint for Q1: if $\frac{a}{b}$ is rational ($a,b$ integers), when is $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ an integer?

Comment: @DanielMroz well $\frac{a^2}{b^2} $ can only be an integer if $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer.

Ah, I see where you've come from now, I can use the fact that if $ p $ divides $a^2 $ then it divides $a$ also and build a contradiction from this.

Comment: @MathewDuxbury:  Yep.  So the only case is when $a=b$.

Comment: Indeed! If $x$ is rational and $x^2$ an integer, then $x$ must also be an integer. So, by contrapositive, if $n$ is an integer and not a perfect square, then $\sqrt n$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is **yes** for primes, and extremely well known.  My favorite of many many proofs is that if for prime $p \ne 1$ we have that if $\sqrt{p} = a/b$ (i.e., were rational), then $p b^2 = a^2$.  The left side has an odd number of prime factors, while the right side has an even number of prime factors.  By the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), this is a contradiction.

The answer to question 2 is **no** for arbitrary reals (since your definition would not apply to $\sqrt{\pi}$ or an infinite number of other real numbers), but **yes** for any natural number, all of which of course have a unique prime factorization.

Comment: Could you direct me to a proof using the Prime Number Theorem? Also for your second part of the answer I'm still unsure how you can show that any combination of square roots of primes the answer will be irrational.

Comment: I've just seen your edit, I'm familiar with FTA and just proved it that way with the rest of your comments. Was a little confused with prime number theorem!

Comment: Yep... I was a bit hasty.  (Sorry.) . The Prime Number Theorem describes the *distributions* of primes amongst $\mathbb{Z}$.